# Como copiar um texto do componente TcxGrid(Tabela)

Tags: delphi-7

Tenho uma tabela que quero copiar o texto dela, assim quando o usuário copiar, ele pode colar em qualquer lugar. porem nas propriedades do componente eu não encontro.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Componentes da DevExpress geralmente tem muita resposta no próprio site deles, veja se essa solução te ajuda: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t269601/copy-values-from-cxgrid-master-detail-to-clipboard

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas encontrei outra forma de copiar a coluna, obrigado.

Comment: de nada, se conseguir compartilhar aqui a resposta da sua pergunta fica bom para todos que estão com esse mesmo problema, boa sorte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não encontrei um meio para copiar diretamente pelos componentes do *tcxGrid*, a princípio ele não aceita a cópia quando é usado de forma de tabela, mas quando é usado por dados do SQL essa alteração é possível, no meu caso como estava usando como *table* tive que criar um menu com a informação "copiar" e nela eu passava os dados com o seguinte comando:

```
uses clipbrd;

Clipboard.AsText := tblMovimentaEstoque.DataController.Values[tblMovimentaEstoque.DataController.FocusedRecordIndex, cxcNf.index];
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]